# Bind template to ReactiveVar array in Meteor

Tags: rest, http, meteor, callback, reactive

I have the following scenario:

I have the following template:

```
<ul>
  {{#each persons}}
     {{Name}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

where `persons = ReactiveVar([])` in the template .js file.
and I'm updating the persons variable in the callback of a HTTP Rest API:

```
var instance = Template.instance();
API(url, (error, result) = instance.persons.set(result)) //result is an array
```

Nothing happens on the UI. How can I fix this? (I am willing to use simple array as well but the condition is to populate the array from an API callback).

Comment: Please show the rest of your helper and `onCreated` code, including where you define `persons`. Otherwise there's not enough to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Binding external APIs to a template can be solved with a classic Template instance' ReactiveVar / ReactiveDict (let's call them reactive source). Note, that you should not make these calls or updates to a reactive source in a helper but rather inside an event or inside onCreated.

Let's take your template:

```js
<ul>
  {{#each persons}}
     {{Name}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

We then make the call inside the onCreated function:

```js
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  const instance = this
  instance.state = new ReactiveDict()
  instance.state.set('persons', [])

  // Template's internal tracker
  instance.autorun(() => {

    API(url, (error, result) => instance.state.set('persons', result)) //result is an array
  })
})
```

And return the data only by the reactive source in the helper:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  persons() {
    return Template.instance().state.get('persons')
  }
})
```

Now this brings another problem: The external API is usually not reactive, causing the `autorun` to **not** trigger again if the data in the external API has changed. If the source would be a Mongo collection, the Template's internal Tracker would automatically re-run and update your `persons` state.

If you want to get the external data only once, it is fine. However, in order to `scan` the external api for changes you have some different options:

**Easy way: use a timer (setInterval):**

```js
let timerId

Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  const instance = this
  instance.state = new ReactiveDict()
  instance.state.set('persons', [])

  timerId = setInterval(() => {
    API(url, (error, result) => instance.state.set('persons', result)) //result is an array
  }, 5000) // scans each 5 seconds for updates
})

Template.myTemplate.onDestroyed(function () {
  if (timerId) {
    clearInterval(timerId)
    timerId = null
  }
})
```

**Pros**

- simple to implement
- fine grained tuning of timing for a fluent experience

**Cons**

- setInterval is a [sink](https://github.com/wisec/domxsswiki/wiki/Sinks)
- you have to clean it up to prevent memory leaks (in onDestroyed)

**Hard way: Let the external API's service call you!**

If you have the option to let the external service [connect and call your app via ddp](https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#DDP-connect) you can let the external service decide, when the data has changed and is ready to fire, so your current app can update automatically.

You need a method and a collection for this:

*server and client:*

```js
export const ExternalData = new Mongo.Collection('externalData')
```

*server:*

```js
import ExternalData from 'path/to/externalData'

Meteor.methods({
  'myApp.updateExternalData'(args) {
     // check permissions...
     // check data integrity...
     const {url} = args
     const {data} = args
     ExternalData.update({url}, {$set: data})
   }
})

Meteor.publish({
 'myApp.externalData'(url) {
   return ExternalData.find({url})
 }
})
```

Now on the client you just need to subscribe to the data and update the reactive var automatically:

*client:*

```js
import ExternalData from 'path/to/externalData'

Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  const instance = this

  // subscribe to changes
  instance.autorun(() => {

    const subscription = this.subscribe('myApp.externalData', url)
    if (subscription.ready()) {
       console.log('myApp.externalData is ready')
    }
  })
})

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  persons() {
    return ExternalData.find({})
  }
})
```

*External Service / APP:*

```js
// if the external app is a meteor app you are lucky and can go with:
// https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#DDP-connect
// Otherwise you can use the npm package:
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/ddp
// For authentication you can use:
// https://github.com/reactioncommerce/meteor-ddp-login
// or
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/ddp-login
const connection = // create a ddp connection

function onDataChanged () {
  const data = //... get data from the backend of your ext. servie
  const url  = //... and the url for which the data is relevant

  // call the app to update the data:
  connection.call('myApp.updateExternalData', {url, data})
}
```

Pros:

- Template automatically updates when the collection updates
- No timers = no sinks!
- Requires no additional reactive variable
- You can use the collection to make external data persistent, cache it or create a revision / history
- You can plug / unplug the external services (better scaling, less dependencies)

Cons:

- High learning curve (but it's worth the effort)
- Works only if you have control over the external service
- More code = more potential errors so more tests to write